# sql using update

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I using pgsql and now need update a column,add '.jpg' in every cell.

```
UPDATE image SET image_tag= image_location + '.jpg'::character varying;
```

but it show

> ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying + character varying
>   LINE 1: UPDATE image SET image_tag= image_location +
>   '.jpg'::charact...
>                                                      ^
>
> HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You
>   might need to add explicit type casts.

**Error**

so how to solve it. thanks!!!

Comment: What is the `::character varying` supposed to do?  Did you try omitting it?

Comment: @Andomar - `x::character varyinng` is as synonym for `CAST(x AS character varying)`.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware, PostgreSQL uses `||` for concatenation, not `+`.

[9.4: String Functions and Operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html)

```
UPDATE image SET image_tag = image_location || '.jpg'
```

Comment: Correct. `||` is the ANSI SQL standard for string concatenation.